# Java JPA Nullity on Attribute

Tags: java, jpa, entity, relation

I am working for now with JPA/Static metamodel and appeared to me a doubt.

Is there any many manner to verify on an SingularAttribute/PluralAttribute if the relation is required (e.g. the annotation OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToOne was annotated with optional=false).

for example

i have this

```
@OneToOne (optional=false,mappedBy = "recordingIsrc")
public Recording<?> recording;
```

I tried to check on API, but always the only alternative is go back to the annotation to check the attribute, but this seems to be a workaround instead to be a model verification.

Kind Regards,

Comment: It is not related. Please compare the questions before flag as duplicate. the other question is about Json/Arrays and this there is nothing to do with "optional" on annotation and staticmetamodel.

Comment: No this is not contained in the MetaModel API

Comment: thanks, i was just to make sure. its a problem because i need to back to the entity, and take a lot of care to find the correct attribute. tks to confirm.

Comment: The meta model is not created for your purpose. It's just there for making Criteria API type safe

Answer (score 0):

This information is not contained in the MetaModel API.

The meta model is not created for your purpose. It's just there for making Criteria API type safe.